# How to open each project's folder in explorer at once in visual studio?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, explorer

In visual studio, i need to copy a dll from one project to all other projects inside the solution. I have nearly 10 projects inside a solution. Is there a way to paste the dll in all projects' bin folder at once?.

Answer (score 0):

Copying dlls from one project to another is not possible.
However, you can right click on dll and in properties see the dll path/location and then include the same dll into your another project based on the path.